# Receiving clickhouse Code: 210. DB::NetException: Net Exception: No route to host (XX.X.X.XX:9000) when trying to connect through remote host

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to connect clickhouse server through clickhouse-client from another node but getting following error:

```sh
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Net Exception: No route to host (xx.xx.xx.xxx:9000)
```

Clickhouse-client works on the same host but not from another server even though I'm able to ping the servers successfully.
I've already tried `<listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>` or `::` or `127.0.0.0` settings in the *config* file, but nothing works.

Comment: It looks like it is a network configuration problem, not CH. Try to access to remote CH by http - *http : //address:8123*  ([CH HTTP Interface](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/)).

Comment: what about through clickhouse-client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running nc -z -v xx.xx.xx.xxx:9000 from where you are trying to connect. If you get the same no route to host error, then the problem is not with clickhouse.

Comment: yes you were right, ports were blocked from these servers

Comment: to be specific, I tried to telnet to other CH node on port 9000/8123, and got no route exception. Once ports were unblocked, issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on my Mac and the console output from `./clickhouse server` indicated that port 9000 was already in use. It was being used by `php-fm` which had been installed via Homebrew. I stopped PHP, restarted the ClickHouse server and was then able to connect.